# Check wether a curve lies on a suface when replacing the curve coordinates on surface doesn't work

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to verify wether the curve $ \overrightarrow{r}(t) = (t^2, t + \frac{1}{3} \cdot t^3, t - \frac{1}{3} \cdot t^3), t\in [-1,2]$ lies on $S: 4x^2 - 3y^2 + 2z^2 = 0 $.

I tried replacing and got
$$ 4t^4 -3 \Big( t + \frac{1}{3} \cdot t^3 \Big)^2 + 2 \Big(t - \frac{1}{3} \cdot t^3 \Big)^2 $$
then
$$ t^6 ( -1/3 + 2/9) + t^4 (4 -2 -4/3) +t^2 (-3+2) = 0$$

$$ -\frac{1}{9} t^6 + \frac{2}{3} t^4 - t^2 = 0 $$
but this last is not true in $[-1,2]$

Where is my mistake or how can I show the curve does lie or doesn't lie on the surface?

Obs.: On Geogebra it really looks like the curve lies on the surface (even for larger intervals).

Comment: Try with $t=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do the complete computation. One quickly sees that the terms in $y^2$ and $z^2$ yield $t^6$ terms when developed, *and these do not cancel out*. Hence $S=0$ cannot hold.